# Remove AM PM in dropdown TextField type=time (react typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I remove option AM PM in dropdown of TextField type=time ?
Now I can remove from input field but still cannot remove it from dropdown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srTw0.png)

And this is my code

```
<TextField 
  sx={{
    width: '49%',
    '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      '&.Mui-focused': {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
      },
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '& > fieldset': { borderColor: '#FFFFFF' },
      '&:hover fieldset': {
        borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
      },
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
      },
      '& .MuiIconButton-root': {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
      },
      '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
      },
      '& input[type="time"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field': {
        display: 'none',
      },
    },
    '& .gform_wrapper_1 div.gfield_time_ampm': {
      display: 'none',
    },
  }}
  label="Time Stop"
  value={selectedTimeStop} 
  type="time" 
  onChange={updateSelectedTimeStop} 
  inputProps={{
    step: "0.001",
    max: '23:59:59.999',
  }}
/>
```

Thank you for suggession!

Comment: It works based on HTML's input time field, which supports AM/PM based on your locale. Meaning if you are using 12Hr format, it will show up, otherwise won't.
Also, I think you can try https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/time-picker/#choose-time-view-renderer for better control.

Comment: I try it already but mui does not support milliseconds that i need to use.

Answer (score 0):

is this solves your prob?

```
 <TextField 
      sx={{
        width: '49%',
        '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          '&.Mui-focused': {
            color: '#FFFFFF',
          },
        },
        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
          '& > fieldset': { borderColor: '#FFFFFF' },
          '&:hover fieldset': {
            borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
          },
          '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
            borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
          },
          '& .MuiIconButton-root': {
            color: '#FFFFFF',
          },
          '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': {
            color: '#FFFFFF',
          },
          '& input[type="time"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field': {
            display: 'none',
          },
        },
        '& .gform_wrapper_1 div.gfield_time_ampm': {
          display: 'none',
        },
      }}
      label="Time Stop"
      value={selectedTimeStop} 
      type="time" 
      onChange={updateSelectedTimeStop} 
      inputProps={{
        step: "0.001",
        max: '23:59:59.999',
        inputMode: "24hour",  <-- passs it 
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but it's not solve. it's still the same, not change anything.